# Python 2.7 Regex; Finding varying number of expressions

Tags: python, arrays, regex, bioinformatics

I am working on a bioinformatics project and am currently trying to split a certain string containing locations on a chromosome.
Example of a few strings, which go by the name "location":

```
 NC_000023.11:g.154532082
 NC_000023.11:g.154532058_154532060
 NC_000023.11:g.154532046
```

What I would like returned looks like:

```
 ([154532082])
 ([154532058], [154532060])
 ([154532046])
```

I can not think of a regex that normally captures only the first number, and when present, separately captures the second number, without creating a second group, as with:

```
re.findall(":g.(\d*)_?(\d*)", location)
which gives:
([154532082], [])
([154532058], [154532060])
([154532046], [])
```

or

```
re.findall(":g.(\d*)", location), re.findall("\d_(\d*)", location)
which gives:
[(154532082), ()]
[(154532058), (154532060)]
[154532046), ()]
```

Is there any expression that would solve this? Or should I see and try to remove the empty lists after finding them the way I do?

Comment: That is just how regex with `re.findall` works, an item will be added for each capturing group in the pattern. You can always filter out unnecessary empty items though.

Comment: Yes, this is not possible. You will have to filter out the empty tuples. But before you do, does this format have a name? There is probably a package out there to read it.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew said `re.findall` works, you first need to split the location string and use it on the right part like: `re.findall("\d+", location.split(":g.")[1])`

Comment: split the string with a dot `.` then get the last piece and split it with `_` - done

Comment: There are  a lot of workrounds. Choose one, try, and come back if you have any more problems.

Comment: The format does not really have a name. It is a data-dump, stored in a horrible .xlsx format.
Using re.findall("\d+", location.split(":g.")[1]) works pretty decent. Only problem is that at the end there seems to be a non-breaking space, but i think I'll ignore it through a try statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do:

```
[re.search("(?<=:g.)(\d*)_?(\d*)", item).group() for item in location.split("\n")]
```

What I did here was to make a list comprehension to do everything in a single line. Going by parts:

```
for item in location.split("\n")
```

This iterates over a list built from the location string, where I split the string in all the line breaks. Now the for loop will iterate over every part of the string between the line breaks. Each of these parts is now called 'item'.

```
re.search("(?<=:g.)(\d*)_?(\d*)", item).group()
```

Here I perform a positive lookbehind assertion, which means that the regex will look for ':g.' (the ?<=:g. part), match everything after that, and ditch the ':g.'. As for group(), this is just to print the match from the re.search() method.

Read the python documentation on regex, it helps a lot:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html